# Is there a way to force close a dropdown menu when going from a from small screen to large screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that I'm building with bootstrap based off this [W3Schools example here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h).

When you are looking at the menu collapsed on a small screen, it looks like this:

[image]

And if you don't click off of the dropdown and expand the screen, the dropdown stays open.

[image]

**Question:**
Is there a way to force close a dropdown menu when you switch from one a small screen to larger one?

**Why I want to do this:**
For my current navbar, I wrote a media query so that when you hover over the dropdown on desktops, you see the menu. I also disabled the the top menu item so the user can't click it.

I have that hover there and I disabled the top link so users don't have to click to open or close the dropdown menu. And that works fine...until you go to a smaller screen size, click the dropdown and then expand the screen again. At that point, the dropdown is open and you have to click off of it again. I want the dropdown to close so the screen is expanded (then the user can go back to hovering over the dropdown menu).

Not sure if this is helpful, but this is the media query I wrote for the large screen/desktop behavior:

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
    /**Background link hover**/

    .navbar .navbar-nav >  li:hover:after{
        width: 100%;
        background: black;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav >  li:after{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        height: 3px;
        width: 0px;
        background: transparent;
        transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
    }

    .dropdown{
        position: relative;
        display:none;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
     .disabled-desktop-link {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
    }

}
```

Comment: js or jquery would be an quick fix. With css could be a lot harder

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I don't mind a js solution (I thought you only added tags for stuff directly related to the problem. I hadn't used js, so I didn't add the tag). I am not TERRIBLY familiar with js, but I found an "onresize" function.  So, I'm seeing if I can use that to update data-toggle="collapse" in the html when the page is a large size.

Comment: You are actually on the right track. If you run into trouble, please post your full code as a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just want a JS event listener on the window, which fires when you resize the window.

Read into this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you add a class `open` to your `li.dropdown` when you click on it. 
So, what you you can do is to remove the class `open` when you resize your window.

Here is a simple way to do it :

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (windowWidth >= 992) // the width you want
        $(".dropdown").removeClass('open');
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/5oquf01q/3/